# Filter extruded buildings by colour according to their construction year in ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I tried to filter my extruded buildings according to their construction year. I saw this example: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/visualization-sm-color-mesh/ and tried it in my code but it did not work. I think the problem is overwrite. Filter not work on extruded ones. How can I solve that?

My Code:

```
require([
    "esri/config",
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/views/SceneView",
    "esri/widgets/BasemapToggle",
    "esri/widgets/BasemapGallery",
    "esri/widgets/CoordinateConversion",

    "esri/Graphic",
    "esri/rest/route",
    "esri/rest/support/RouteParameters",
    "esri/rest/support/FeatureSet",
    "esri/widgets/Search",
    "esri/rest/locator",

    "esri/layers/SceneLayer",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
    "esri/widgets/Sketch/SketchViewModel",
    "esri/widgets/Expand",
    "esri/widgets/DirectLineMeasurement3D",
    "esri/widgets/AreaMeasurement3D",
    "esri/widgets/LayerList",
    "esri/widgets/Home",
    "esri/widgets/Editor",
    "esri/symbols/LabelSymbol3D",
    "esri/layers/support/LabelClass",
    "esri/rest/support/Query",
    "esri/widgets/Slider",
    "esri/widgets/Legend",
    "esri/smartMapping/renderers/color",
    "esri/widgets/smartMapping/ColorSlider"



], function (esriConfig, Map, MapView, SceneView, BasemapToggle, BasemapGallery, CoordinateConversion,
 Graphic, route, RouteParameters, FeatureSet, Search, locator, SceneLayer, FeatureLayer, GraphicsLayer, 
 SketchViewModel, Expand, DirectLineMeasurement3D,AreaMeasurement3D,LayerList, Home,Editor,LabelSymbol3D,LabelClass,Query, 
 Slider,Legend, colorRendererCreator, ColorSlider) {

    // the layer where the graphics are sketched
    const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer({
    elevationInfo: { mode: "on-the-ground" },
    title: "Sketch GraphicsLayer"
    });

    esriConfig.apiKey = "AAPKf5c475a3978645a98668967366a26024mPzkb7hImO8bP4L5d0NOR0KEkZKgo43uf6wARoLkaCxI5DS9h6gBWpy7jfPvpaF3";

    const footprintBuildings = new FeatureLayer({
        url:
            "https://arcgis.geotech-company.com/server/rest/services/Hosted/Hacettepe_Buildings/FeatureServer",
        renderer: {
            type: "simple",
            symbol: {
                type: "polygon-3d",
                symbolLayers: [
                    {
                        type: "fill",
                        material: { color: [255, 237, 204] },
                        outline: { color: [133, 108, 62, 0.5] }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        
        visible: false
    });

    

    const extrudedBuildings = new FeatureLayer({
        url:
            "https://arcgis.geotech-company.com/server/rest/services/Hosted/Hacettepe_Buildings/FeatureServer",
            
            
        renderer: {
            type: "simple",
            symbol: {
                type: "polygon-3d",
                symbolLayers: [
                    {
                        type: "extrude",
                        material: { color: [222, 16, 16, 0.9] },
                        edges: {
                            type: "solid",
                            color: [133, 108, 62, 0.5],
                            size: 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            visualVariables: [
                {
                    type: "size",
                    field: "yukseklik",
                    valueUnit: "meters"
                }
            ]

        },


    const map = new Map({
        basemap: "satellite",
        layers: [graphicsLayer,footprintBuildings, extrudedBuildings],
        ground: "world-elevation"
    });


   
    const view = new SceneView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,

        camera: {
            position: {
                x: 32.736299, //Longitude
                y: 39.850315, //Latitude
                z: 2400 //Meters
            },
            heading: 356.82,
            tilt: 55
        },
        qualityProfile: "high"
        
          
    });



          ///// constructer year filtre deneme:

    layer = extrudedBuildings;
    
    const colorParams = {
      layer:extrudedBuildings,
      view: view,
      field: "yapim_yili",    // construction year
      theme: "above-and-below",
      minValue: 1990,
      maxValue: 2023,
      edgesType: "solid"
    };
    
    // Generate a continuous color renderer based on the
    // statistics of the data in the provided layer
    // and field.
    //
    // This resolves to an object containing several helpful
    // properties, including color scheme, statistics,
    // the renderer and visual variable
    
    colorRendererCreator
      .createContinuousRenderer(colorParams)
      .then((response) => {
        // set the renderer to the layer
    
        layer.renderer = response.renderer;
        if (!layer.visible) {
          layer.visible = true;
        }
    
        // Create the ColorSlider and configure it
        // so it matches the statistics and visual
        // variable generated by the color renderer creator
    
        const colorSlider = new ColorSlider({
          primaryHandleEnabled: true,
          container: "slider",
          min: response.statistics.min,
          max: response.statistics.max,
          stops: response.visualVariable.stops,
          labelFormatFunction: (value) => {
            return value.toFixed(0);
          }
        });
        // Since data represents years, we don't
        // want values to show decimal places
        colorSlider.viewModel.precision = 0;
        //view.ui.add("containerDiv", "bottom-left");
    
        // when the user slides the handle(s), update the renderer
        // with the updated color visual variable stops
    
        function changeEventHandler() {
          const renderer = layer.renderer.clone();
          const colorVariable = renderer.visualVariables[0].clone();
          colorVariable.stops = colorSlider.stops;
          renderer.visualVariables = [colorVariable];
          layer.renderer = renderer;
        }
    
        colorSlider.on(
          ["thumb-change", "thumb-drag", "min-change", "max-change"],
          changeEventHandler
        );
      })
      .catch(console.error);
```

Problem:
Buildings can not extrude and slider is not work.
[image]

Comment: "Did not work" is not a very useful problem description. What does it do instead? What error is generated? What portion of the code have you identified to be the problem? Please [Edit] the Question for clarity.

Comment: Is it more descriptive now?